# Mysql Update a username

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to update views and add 1 more view this is the code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `skins` WHERE `username` = '$name'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $views = $row['views'];
    $rank = $row['rank'];
    $addv = $views + 1;
    echo "id $id HI $username, gledaniq $views rank $rank sled gledaneto trqbva da ima $addv";
    $sql2 = "UPDATE `skins` SET `views` = `$addv` WHERE `username` = `$username`";
    $sql3 = mysql_query($sql2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shankar is correct, but should you not simply be doing (outside of the loop):

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE `skins` SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE `username` = '$name'";
$sql3 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

The way you have it now, if the first query returns more than 1 result, you are going to be incrementing the views on each 'skin' by more than 1 (if 1st query returns 3 skins, you'll add 3 views to each skin).

Answer (score -1):

In your `$sql2` statement , don't use backticks here , use a single quote instead

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE `skins` SET `views` = `$addv` WHERE `username` = `$username`";
                                    --^-----^               -----^---------^
```